# Android Cannot see anything inside data folder

Tags: android, database, sqlite, adb

i am trying to see SQLite database in anyway possible (I have a rooted device). I tried File explorer in eclipse but i cannot see anything under data folder. Can anybody please help me with this
I tried to search everywhere but couldnt find a clear solution. 
I also tried adb shell but i cannot see list of things inside data folder using "ls" command.
error
Opendir failed. Permission denied

I am guessing this has something to do with rights but how can i fix it

Please help

Comment: are you trying to see database using emulator or device?

Answer (score 2):

You need root premission to explore `DATA` directory... 
`From phone`
I use `terminal emulator` to do the job..... Simply open `terminal` then type in `su` after that it will ask for premision. then you need to type `cd data/data/WhereEverYouNeedToGo/databases` and `"WhereEverYouNeedToGo"` should be package name. After that you could do whatever you want with your database.

`from PC`

open `terminal` or `cmd` goto your `adb` directory then run `adb shell` then `su` and then
`cd data/data/WhereEverYouNeedToGo/databases`

Hope it helped.

Comment: It will probably be much more convenient to do all that typing from an adb session than an on device terminal.  But doing it on the device may make more sense if you discover a puzzling problem while away from a laptop/desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Run adb in root mode using "adb root"

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell
su
ls /data/
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You have been given a number of answers for how to leverage the root capability, however as android is designed without the assumption of root there are other methods as well which you can use while developing apps.

1) Include functionality on an expert menu to copy the database to the sdcard; there is no file copy method in android java (and in most stock cases no 'cp' shell command), but you can find numerous answers here with a copy routine.

2) Make your apk debuggable and use the run-as command to obtain a shell running as the application userid and starting in the app's data directory.  You can then copy the database to the sdcard if the app has that permission.

3) Have your app set the permissions on the database file **during development** to world readable.  Although you cannot browse the directory tree to down to it, you can then adb pull the database file by giving it's full path name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have either routed device or your device should be a "Android Dev Phone" to explore that directory. Trying checking the same using emulator, you will be able to see the data folder contents.